# Ext Js - Excluding a value while sorting

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a combobox which can have values for all the US cities.
In this combo box, I want to show 'None Selected' as the first value and other values should be sorted alphabetically.So I need to exclued 'None selected' while I sort the store.
How to achieve this in ext js sorting ?

Comment: Can you provide example code of what you are currently trying?

Comment: If you have both a "value" and "display" field in your model, you could also do a hack like setting the "None Selected" record's value to be something like "_none" or some other value that will always sort to the top with ASC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Asp.Net MVC , i am using this way :

```
var myList= (List<Country>())CommonLogic.GetAllCountries();
myList.Add(new Country() {Id = -1, Name= "None selected" });
myList= liste.OrderBy(p => p.Id).ToList();
ViewData["countries"] = myList;
```

Or you can use emptyText option :

```
var countryCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Country',
    renderTo: 'countryCombo ',
    displayField: 'Name',
    width: 500,
    labelWidth: 130,
    store: store,
    queryMode: 'local',
    typeAhead: true,
    emptyText : 'None Selected'
});
```